# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_keras_mask'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, nlp-question-answering

I am writing a Few shots Q&A model using Triple layer loss.  I am able to train my model but when I try to predict I get the above error.

I have given below experts of my code for reference.  I have tried by checking the data types and other factors but no luck.

Could someone let me know what is going wrong here?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv(r'/content/IAS16_standard.csv',encoding = "latin1")
rev_df = (df.drop('Questions', axis=1)
             .join
             (
             df.Questions
             .str
             .split(',',expand=True)
             .stack()
             .reset_index(drop=True, level=1)
             .rename('Questions')           
             ))
train=rev_df[['Questions','Intent']]
train.reset_index(drop=True)

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
module_url = 'https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/4'
# Import the Universal Sentence Encoder's TF Hub module
embed = hub.load(module_url)

import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import keras
import keras.backend as K
from keras.layers import *
from keras.callbacks import *
from keras.optimizers import *
from keras import Model
from keras.layers.core import Lambda, Flatten, Dense
from keras.layers import Bidirectional, LSTM
import pickle    
import os
input_text1 = Input(shape=(512,))
x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(input_text1)
x = Dropout(0.4)(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.001))(x)
x = Dropout(0.4)(x)
dense_layer = Dense(128, name='dense_layer')(x)
norm_layer = Lambda(lambda  x: K.l2_normalize(x, axis=1), name='norm_layer')(dense_layer)

model=Model(inputs=[input_text1], outputs=norm_layer)

model.summary()
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 512)]             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 256)               131328    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization (BatchNo (None, 256)               1024      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 64)                16448     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_layer (Dense)          (None, 128)               8320      
_________________________________________________________________
norm_layer (Lambda)          (None, 128)               0         
=================================================================
Total params: 157,120
Trainable params: 156,608
Non-trainable params: 512

from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Layer

# Input for anchor, positive and negative images
in_a = Input(shape=(512,))
in_p = Input(shape=(512,))
in_n = Input(shape=(512,))

# Output for anchor, positive and negative embedding vectors
# The nn4_small model instance is shared (Siamese network)
emb_a = model(in_a)
emb_p = model(in_p)
emb_n = model(in_n)

class TripletLossLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, alpha, **kwargs):
        self.alpha = alpha
        super(TripletLossLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    
    def triplet_loss(self, inputs):
        a, p, n = inputs
        p_dist = K.sum(K.square(a-p), axis=-1)
        n_dist = K.sum(K.square(a-n), axis=-1)
        return K.sum(K.maximum(p_dist - n_dist + self.alpha, 0), axis=0)
    
    def call(self, inputs):
        loss = self.triplet_loss(inputs)
        self.add_loss(loss)
        return loss

# Layer that computes the triplet loss from anchor, positive and negative embedding vectors
triplet_loss_layer = TripletLossLayer(alpha=0.4, name='triplet_loss_layer')([emb_a, emb_p, emb_n])

# Model that can be trained with anchor, positive negative images
nn4_small2_train = Model([in_a, in_p, in_n], triplet_loss_layer)

nn4_small2_train.summary()

__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)            [(None, 512)]        0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_3 (InputLayer)            [(None, 512)]        0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_4 (InputLayer)            [(None, 512)]        0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
model (Functional)              (None, 128)          157120      input_2[0][0]                    
                                                                 input_3[0][0]                    
                                                                 input_4[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
triplet_loss_layer (TripletLoss ()                   0           model[0][0]                      
                                                                 model[1][0]                      
                                                                 model[2][0]                      
==================================================================================================
Total params: 157,120
Trainable params: 156,608
Non-trainable params: 512

unique_train_label=np.array(train['Intent'].unique().tolist())
labels_train=np.array(train['Intent'].tolist())
map_train_label_indices = {label: np.flatnonzero(labels_train == label) for label in unique_train_label}

def get_triplets(unique_train_label,map_train_label_indices):
      label_l, label_r = np.random.choice(unique_train_label, 2, replace=True)
      a, p = np.random.choice(map_train_label_indices[label_l],2, replace=True)
      n = np.random.choice(map_train_label_indices[label_r])
      return a, p, n

def get_triplets_batch(k,train_set,unique_train_label,map_train_label_indices,embed):

    while True:
      idxs_a, idxs_p, idxs_n = [], [], []
      for _ in range(k):
          a, p, n = get_triplets(unique_train_label,map_train_label_indices)
          idxs_a.append(a)
          idxs_p.append(p)
          idxs_n.append(n)

      a=train_set.iloc[idxs_a].values.tolist()
      b=train_set.iloc[idxs_p].values.tolist()
      c=train_set.iloc[idxs_n].values.tolist()

      a = embed(a)
      p = embed(b)
      n = embed(c)
        # return train_set[idxs_a], train_set[idxs_p], train_set[idxs_n]
      yield [a,p,n] , []

nn4_small2_train.compile(loss=None, optimizer='adam')
nn4_small2_train.fit(get_triplets_batch(128,train['Questions'],unique_train_label,map_train_label_indices,embed), epochs=100,steps_per_epoch=10)

X_train = model.predict({'input_1':embed(np.stack(np.array(train['Questions'].values.tolist())))})

y_train = np.array(train['Intent'].values.tolist())
```

The last but one line is giving the error.

Comment: I think I understand that the line with the issue is `X_train = model.predict(...`. Is that correct? You are passing a dictionary into the predict method, but the predict method expects either a Numpy array, list of arrays, TensorFlow tensor or list of tensors, a tf.data dataset, a generator, or a keras.utils.Sequence. A dictionary is not one of these.https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict

Comment: Yes that is correct.  However I am using tensor hub sentence encoder to convert the sentences into a tensor using embed function before passing into the predict method.  Is that not a correct way?  I might be missing something here.  Many thanks